# How to map unique ID to each lane items with multiple conditions

Tags: r

I have two files with huge data set, below is the sample data mentioned,

[image]

Trying to map Unique BIN number from 2nd file to 1st one(output as below)
I am able to create this in excel by using the **countif** function with multiple conditions but unable to do it in R. pls help to create code for the same.
Can you explain how to build this logic using R

Comment: post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).  it looks like you need to table join.  there are a few popular packages to do this.

Comment: It would be easier to help if you create a small reproducible example along with expected output. Read about [how to give a reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269).